# Realm Cocoa with GraphQL Interfaces

Tags: cocoa, realm

GraphQL has multiple inheritance through Interface types and Realm has single inheritance. What are some scalable, general solutions to modeling Interfaces in Realm?

Additionally, here are two options I've explored for ideation. It would be helpful to know if the following two solutions seem reasonable, unreasonable, or have unlisted issues.

1. STI
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance

   - pros

     - easy to sort by key path on Interface type
   - cons

     - lots of merged Interfaces will lead to very sparse Realm Objects with lots not nils on most fields
     - confusing semantics where 1 object type really represents multiple types in which case requires an additional interface above realm object model to better manage behavior
2. Relationship based inheritance

   - E.g. psuedo-code of Realm object:

     ```
     InterfaceType: RLMObject {
         // Only 1 of these is not `nil`, that is the concrete type
         subTypeA: SubTypeA?
         subTypeB: SubTypeB?
         subTypeC: SubTypeC?
     }
     SubTypeA: RLMObject { ... }
     SubTypeB: RLMObject { ... }
     SubTypeC: RLMObject { ... }
     ```
   - pros

     - More readable
     - Less sparse `nil`s
   - cons

     - Sorting on a key on the Interface type is difficult

       - Can duplicate sort keys across Interface and subtypes, but may be challenging to keep keys that may mutate up to date across the parent and sub types
       - Could create a separate index on sort keys for sub types on the fly but implementation may be difficult

Comment: Why do you say that for option 2 sorting on a key on the interface type is difficult? You'd just sort on `subTypeX.key` instead of `key`.

Comment: Because the X there is arbitrary to the sort on the Interface type. You can't do `subTypeA.key || subTypeB.key || subTypeC.key` if you're sorting the collection of all types under the interface (or a subset of the types). As far as I understand, you can only use specific key paths. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, you have a valid point there.

Comment: So... Thoughts on what the best option is?